# Trying to show the updated msql row after successfully updating a form using php

Tags: php, forms

I would like to have a confirmation page where it can show what are the results of an updated form using php.

I have the edit.php form, and I also created an updated.php page, where I want to show the results of the edited rows.

### edit.php

```
<?php

//get ID sent by GET collection
$parentID = $_GET['id'];

ob_start();

include('connection.php');
include('functions.php');

//query the database with client ID
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$parentID'";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

//if result is returned
if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {

    //we have data
    //set some variables
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
            $parentName = $row['p_name'];
            $parentEmail = $row['email'];
            $studentName = $row['s_name'];
            $parentPhone = $row['phone'];
            $notes = $row['notes'];
            $parentDeposit = $row['deposit'];
            $packageNotColl = $row['Package-NotCollected'];
            $depositNotColl = $row['deposit-not-collected'];
        }
    } else {
            $alertMessage = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>Nothing to see here.<a href='list.php'>Head back</a></div>";
}

// id update button was submitted
if( isset( $_POST['update'] ) ) {
    //set variables
    $parentName = validateFormData( $_POST['parentName'] );
    $parentEmail = validateFormData( $_POST['parentEmail'] );
    $studentName = validateFormData( $_POST['studentName'] );
    $parentPhone = validateFormData( $_POST['parentPhone'] );
    $notes = validateFormData( $_POST['notes'] );
    $parentDeposit = validateFormData( $_POST['parentDeposit'] );

    //create new database query result
    $query = "UPDATE users
                SET p_name = '$parentName',
                email = '$parentEmail',
                s_name = '$studentName',
                phone = '$parentPhone',
                notes = '$notes',
                deposit = '$parentDeposit'
                WHERE id ='$parentID'";
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

    if( $result ) {
        //redirect to client page with query string
        header("Location: updated.php?alert=updatesuccess");
        return $result;
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

if( isset( $_POST['delete'] ) ) {

    $alertMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this profile? This action cannot be undone!</p><br>
                        <form action='". htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) ."?id=$parentID' method='post'>
                            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' name='confirm-delete' value='Yes, delete!'>
                            <a type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' data-dismiss='alert'>Maybe not this time.</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>";

}

if( isset( $_POST['confirm-delete'] ) ) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$parentID'";
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

    if($result) {
        header("Location: list.php?alert=deleted");
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting client: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

include('header.php');

?>

<h1>Edit Profile</h1>

<?php echo $alertMessage; ?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ); ?>?id=<?php echo $parentID; ?>" method="post" class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="parent-name">Parent Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="client-name" name="parentName" value="<?php echo $parentName; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="parent-email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="client-email" name="parentEmail" value="<?php echo $parentEmail; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="student-name">Student Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="student-name" name="studentName" value="<?php echo $studentName; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="parent-phone">Phone #</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="parent-phone" name="parentPhone" value="<?php echo $parentPhone; ?>">
    </div><div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="student-name">Notes</label>
        <input type="textarea" class="form-control input-lg" id="notes" name="notes" value="<?php echo $notes; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="parent-deposit">Deposit</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="parent-deposit" name="parentDeposit" value="<?php echo $parentDeposit; ?>">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <hr>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pull-left" name="delete">Delete</button>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="list.php" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Cancel</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" name="update">Update</button>
            <!-- <a href="updated.php?id<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Print</a> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<hr>
<div>
    <?php if($packageNotColl > 0) { ?>
        <div class='col-sm-3 alert alert-danger'>Package not collected 2018: $<?php echo $packageNotColl; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>    
</div>

<?php

include('footer.php');
?>
```

---

### updated.php

```
<?php

//get ID sent by GET collection
$parentID = $_GET['id'];

ob_start();

include('connection.php');
include('functions.php');

//query the database with client ID
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$parentID'";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

mysqli_close($conn);

include('header.php');

?>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Parent Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Phone #</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Deposit</th>      
            <th>Edit</th>      
        </tr>


    <?php

        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //we have data
                //output the data
                while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                    echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['p_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['s_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td><td>" . $row['deposit'] . "</td>"; 

                    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>';

                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            } else { //if no entries
                echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>You have no clients!</div>";
            } 
        } 

    ?>

<?php

include('footer.php');
?>
```

---

The updated.php page shows the table, but does not include any sql query results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header('Location: ...)` returns the uri/url you provide to the browser, which then calls this page. any information your script had, when you called that redirection, is gone, since it's a different request.

Hence, you should add the id to the url you provide. Like

```
header('Location: /updated.php?id='.$parentID.'&alert=deleted');
```

*However* You **really** should prevent the sql injection that's just waiting to happen. PLEASE read up on how to prevent it, because your script is vulnerable to it. Your script is also vulnerable to XSS. Sanitize ALL externally provided data (`$parentID = $_GET['id'];` should at the very least be `$parentId = intval($_GET['id'])` to fight XSS).

Comment: Jakumi, Thank you. I did not know how to add both the id and the alert in the header parameter. But your message was very helpful. The only thing I changed from your code, is that I removed the single quotes and the dots, because it was not working like that. So I just left it header("Location: /updated.php?id=$parentID&alert=updatesuccess"); I will continue researching on the sanitize options to prevent any sql injections.